C# and EntityFramworkCore: Error after running "$ dotnet ef database update".: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
I am building a website using the entity framework for databases and I got this error after simply renaming a field and removing another
this is the last migration added:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace Server.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class SmallChanges : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
                name: "Balace",
                table: "accounts",
                newName: "Balance");

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<float>(
                name: "Price",
                table: "CurrentStock",
                type: "float",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: 0f);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "Price",
                table: "CurrentStock");

            migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
                name: "Balance",
                table: "accounts",
                newName: "Balace");
        }
    }
}

And then there are three tables in the database that look like this:
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Item OrderItem { get; set; }

    public String Adress { get; set; } 
    
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Order() 
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Date = DateTime.Now;
    }
}   

public class Item 
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Stock { get; set; }

    public string? Buyer { get; set; }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public float Price { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Item() 
    {
        Price = 0.0f;
        Date = DateTime.Now;
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }


}

public class Account 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName {get; set;}

    public string LastName {get; set;}

    public string Email {get; set;}

    public string Password {get; set;}

    public double Balance {get; set;}
 
    public DateTime Date {get; set;} 


    public Account() 
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.Date = DateTime.Now;
    }

}

I thought maybe the issue was with the Item reference in the order class but it worked before this last migration. I am not exactly sure what I am supposed to do here.
I tried running database update and I also tried removing and reading the migrations but I get the same issue. I also tried looking at the migration class to see if anything was wrong but everything looks like it should work.
this is the full error:
Build started...
Build succeeded.
The Entity Framework tools version '7.0.9' is older than that of the runtime '7.0.11'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes. See https://aka.ms/AAc1fbw for more information.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='MandAMarketplace' AND TABLE_NAME='__EFMigrationsHistory';
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='MandAMarketplace' AND TABLE_NAME='__EFMigrationsHistory';
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT `MigrationId`, `ProductVersion`
      FROM `__EFMigrationsHistory`
      ORDER BY `MigrationId`;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20402]
      Applying migration '20240507231333_SmallChanges'.
Applying migration '20240507231333_SmallChanges'.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MySQLMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(RenameColumnOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.<>c.<.cctor>b__82_22(MigrationsSqlGenerator g, MigrationOperation o, IModel m, MigrationCommandListBuilder b)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MySQLMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IModel model, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateUpSql(Migration migration, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MySQLMigrator.GenerateUpSql(Migration migration, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.<>c__DisplayClass16_2.<GetMigrationCommandLists>b__2()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.


Update MySql provider or switch to Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql which is better from many perspectives. Or create ticket for Oracle's .NET team.

For Anyone who comes across the same issues, I am still not sure what the original issue was exactly, but the error occurred when I tried to rename a field. The solution was to remove it and re-add it
